# Ele é um puto, um putinho, um miúdo, ou nenhum dos três?

Tags: significado, diferenças-regionais

Como falante de pt-BR, e sabendo que essas palavras tem significados completamente diferentes em pt-PT, eu procuro dados mais específicos quanto ao seus usos, principalmente no tocante à idade do menino:

1- Um menino com idade inferior a 1 ano já pode ser considerado um putinho?

2- Com qual idade, aproximadamente, um putinho passa a ser um puto?

3- Aproximadamente com qual idade deixa de sê-lo?

4- Podemos nos referir a um adolescente de 13 anos como um puto?

5- E quanto aos miúdos?

p.s. Sei que não existe nenhuma classificação formal, por nenhum órgão normatizador do uso da língua, mas procuro dados aproximados. Mesmo não havendo consenso quanto aos limites de idade, deve haver um consenso quanto às idades que não estão nos limites. Por exemplo, um menino de xxx anos não seria chamado de "putinho".  Um adolescente de xxx anos não seria chamado de "puto".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minha resposta é baseada na minha vivência no distrito de Braga, Portugal.

1. Não se usa de forma alguma. É um bebé nessa idade.
2. Uma criança é «puto» desde que começa a andar até à idade da adolescência, na maioria dos casos.
3. Na verdade, só deixas de ser um «puto», quando começas a trabalhar e a construir família. Mas, eu diria que até aos 13 é mais usado e que depois cai em decréscimo com o decorrer da idade.
4. Claro, mas também depende da idade de quem faz a referência.
5. Eu diria que «miúdo» ou «miúda» é mais usado que «puto», «puto» é usado mais como gíria. Mais formalmente seria «criança».

Eu diria que até aos 20/25 anos pode ser chamado de puto, dependendo da idade de quem está falar. Por exemplo, eu com 32 anos poderia bem dizer ao meu primo de 23:

> Ó puto deixa-te disso... O raio do puto acha que já acha que é alguém.

Mas com certeza que é mais usado desde que deixa de ser bebé até que é adolescente:

> O puto não pára um minuto, parece que tem bichos carpinteiros.

Neste caso é mais usado indiretamente, quando falas com alguém sobre a «criança».

Comment: Interessante.  Eu não imaginava que fosse aplicável a alguém com mais de 12-13 anos.  No Brasil dizemos que o guri está com bicho carpinteiro, no singular.  Por sinal, não sei quem inventou isso ou se realmente existe algum bicho com esse nome. Ou se seria um "apelido" para o cupim.

Comment: @Centaurus tenha em atenção que a partir dos 12/13 pode ser encarado como depreciativo, pelo facto de não ter maturidade. "Os putos que entram agora na universidade não têm juízo nenhum". O que seria "cupim"?

Comment: cupim?    É a palavra mais comum em pt-BR para se referir aos térmitas que devoram madeira.

Comment: @Centaurus aqui chamamos de bicho da madeira mesmo.

Comment: escaravelho (ou bicho carpinteiro) é diferente de cupim,

Comment: @JorgeB. como diz o Peixoto, o cupim (térmita da madeira, uma formiga) não é o nosso bicho da madeira. O cupim são térmitas; são animais *sociais*, e fazem um formigueiro. O bicho da madeira é um animal diferente, talvez um escaravelho. Não fazem colónia, apesar de poderem viver muitos na mesma área. Procura por imagens de cada um.

Comment: Eu acho mais provável um puto de 2, 3, 10 anos ser referido por *puto* que um mais velho ou de meses. Mas, pelo menos cá por baixo, também se chama *puto* a um puto de 3, 6, ou 9 meses. Agora, *putinho* é que eu não ouço, e acho que vale a pena dizer isso. Tu já ouviste, @Centaurus, ou imaginaste só? *Putozinho* ainda vá, mas também é raro. E usa-se para adolescentes e jovens adultos, sempre por locutores mais velhos, para enfatizar a juventude ou imaturidade, mas não necessariamente com sentido pejorativo. Exempo: aquela gaja já tem 40 anos e anda agora com um puto de 25.

Comment: @Jacinto   Não, nunca ouvi "putinho", mas li em uma revista brasileira que é usado para meninos pequenos em Portugal.  Contudo, nada melhor do que um Português nativo para dizer o que é, e o que não é usado em pt-PT.  Obrigado.